# Heavy Constructors or use a method

Tags: c#

Both of these methods are kind of working for me, but I'm not sure what the recommendation would be from a "good practice" point of view.

I have a class which performs various control functions within my library, so needs to initialise all sorts of objects and properties.

Is it okay to put all this logic in the constructor for the class, or should I put it in an "Initialise" method.

```
public MyClass()
{
    mSubObjectA = new mSubObjectA();
    mSubObjectA.DoStuff();
    mSubObjectA.DoMoreStuff();

    mSubObjectB = new mSubObjectB();
    mSubObjectC = new mSubObjectC();

    if (something)
    {
        DoStuff();
    }
    else
    {
        MagicHappens();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how many constructors you think you will have. Don't repeat code. If all of these steps will only happen in your one constructor, it's not a problem. If you're looking to do something more fancy, intelligently arrange your code.

Comment: Wasn't sure which answer to accept, as the Factory discussion was most useful, but as I didn't end up actually using that in this case, but arranged my code better, I guess this is it. :)

Answer (score 7):

Personally I like an object to be fully operational by the time I receive it. On the other hand, doing a lot of work in the constructor *does* smell somewhat.

One alternative is to write a static factory method (or a factory class<sup>*</sup>) which can do all the work it needs to *before* calling the constructor, and then make the constructor itself pretty straightforward. You can choose to expose the simple constructor or not, depending on your requirements.

<sup>*</sup> A factory class can make for better testability, and allows for potentially *different* factory implementations. On the other hand, at that point you've got a pretty hefty level of abstraction going on, which can be a distraction.

Comment: Testability is exactly where this is coming from - I've started with NUnit and am having all sorts of problems isolating parts for testing - if that doesn't smell bad then I don't know what does!  At the moment a lot of stuff needs to be setup before the class can operate.

Comment: @Cylindric: It will partly depend on who's really responsible for that setup. Does it have to be that class? Should that setup part be accessible?

Comment: @Jon Skeet I agree with the Factory Class 100%, but I'd like to say that the distraction of the extra abstraction can be a good thing since it make you notice something is going on other than just `new`. We use quite a bit of CSLA where I work and there is a lot of work going on during instantiation and it's good that you can't just call new.

Comment: @msarchet: In my experience it's *very* context-sensitive. It's hard to give a general "best practice" other than to be open to various options :)

Comment: I'm not sure I need a full-on factory in my case at the moment (although I will need to read into some of these patterns a lot more), as all the relationships and types are known, but I'll probably rework it so that the constructor just initialises objects and private things, and then use Initialise() for the heavy lifting.

Comment: @Cylindric: I would strongly advise *against* an `Initialise` method. Aside from anything else, it *immediately* precludes you from making the type immutable. It also means that it's an extra step for every client to call... which really isn't pleasant.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I agree extremely context-sensitive. I just wanted to give a differing view point. Like all abstractions it's in how and when they are applied that makes them good.

Comment: @Jon: Hmm, I see your point regarding Init().  I'll try and think of a more aesthetic way of architecting it all.  I don't think immutability is an issue in *this* case, but some of the setup being done involves loading external data, and I don't like that in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative to both - use a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) class or [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Constructing complex object graphs is what the factory pattern is about - sounds like a very good fit to your situation.